# Passing and Returning structs C

Tags: c, function, struct

So I have had this problem where I keep getting error codes only in my main that (1) The struct has already been defined when I keep my struct in a header file and (2) I am using incompatible pointer types.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "functDefs.h"
#include "writeToFile.c"
#include "readFile.c"
#include "inputContactInfo.c"
#include "contactInfoStruct.h"

int main(void) {

    int i = 0;
    char *ynAns;
    struct contactId *contactInfo;
    contactInfo = malloc(sizeof(struct contactId));

    do {
            if(ynAns != NULL) {
                    free(ynAns);
            }
            ynAns = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
            printf("\nDo you wish to enter a new contact (Yes or No)?: ");
            fgets(ynAns, 5, stdin);
            ynAns[(strlen(ynAns) - 1)] = '\0';
            if (strcmp(ynAns, "Yes") == 0) {
                    printf("\n");
                    contactInfo = realloc(contactInfo, sizeof(struct contactId) * (i + 1));
                    contactInfo[i] = inputContactInfo();
                    i++;
            }

    } while(strcmp(ynAns, "No") != 0);

    writeToFile(contactInfo, i);

    readFile(i);

    free(contactInfo);
    return 0;
}
```

Then here are my function definitions:

```
void writeToFile(struct contactId *contInfo, int numContacts);
struct contactId *inputContactInfo();
void readFile(int numContacts);
```

And this is the struct header file:

```
struct contactId {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    char companyName[50];
    char phoneNumber[15];
    char email[50];
};
```

I get errors like:

```
IOlist.c: In function ‘main’:
IOlist.c:28:40: error: incompatible types when assigning to     type ‘struct contactId’ from type ‘struct contactId *’
                     contactInfo[i] = inputContactInfo();
                                    ^
IOlist.c:34:21: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘writeToFile’  from incompatible pointer type
     writeToFile(contactInfo, i);
                 ^
In file included from IOlist.c:5:0:
writeToFile.c:7:6: note: expected ‘struct contactId *’ but  argument is of type ‘struct contactId *’
void writeToFile(struct contactId *contInfo, int numContacts)   {
     ^
```

And these errors as well:

```
In file included from IOlist.c:5:0:
writeToFile.c:7:6: error: conflicting types for ‘writeToFile’
void writeToFile(struct contactId *contInfo, int numContacts)  {
     ^
In file included from IOlist.c:4:0:
functDefs.h:1:6: note: previous declaration of ‘writeToFile’  was here
void writeToFile(struct contactId *contInfo, int numContacts);
     ^
In file included from readFile.c:4:0,
             from IOlist.c:6:
contactStruct.h:1:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct contact’
struct contact {
       ^
In file included from writeToFile.c:4:0,
             from IOlist.c:5:
contactStruct.h:1:8: note: originally defined here
 struct contact {
        ^
```

Comment: The  'these errors as well' stuff come in part from the fact that you've not ensured that the compiler knows that `struct contactId` exists before you declare the `writeToFile()` function.  The type in the prototype is known only in the prototype.  Simply add the line `struct contactId;` at the top of the function header and the problems will probably go away (or there'll be a different set of issues to deal with).

Answer (score 1):

Your function inputContactInfo() returns a pointer to struct. But the place where it tries to returnn pointer is a struct. You need declare  struct contactId **contactInfo, allocate memory for each element, and then you can correctly assign your pointer to contactInfo[i].